# Android HashMap not returning object's name

Tags: android, list, object, hashmap, android-arrayadapter

I want to show all task names from database to listView, but it shows only their object id (or name or w.) like this

> com.zcutuhacek.tasker.Task@41a826d0
>   com.zcutuhacek.tasker.Task@41a465d4
>   ...

I call the function, it returns list of my objects (tasks)

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

            DatabaseTaskHandler db = new DatabaseTaskHandler(ListActivity.this);
            List<Task> list = db.getAllTasks();
            ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
            return true;
        }

         private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

                HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

                public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                    List<Task> list) {
                  super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
                  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                    mIdMap.put(list.get(i), i);
                  }
                }

              }

    }
```

I tried to change HashMap to `HashMap<Task, Integer>`, also I tried to use getter of my object and objects name when I put it to HashMap:

```
list.get(i).get_name()
list.get(i)._name
```

When I wrote to log what am I putting to HashMap, it displayed succesfully. I tried both with or without `.toString()`, but it's allways just as I wrote at beginning.

This is method returning the list of tasks:

```
public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Task task = new Task();
            task.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            task.set_name(cursor.getString(1));
            // Adding contact to list
            taskList.add(task);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } 
    return taskList;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, please? Thanks

Comment: Implement toString of Task class.

Comment: That will be the address or internal name, Post the code regarding the database storage of the task name and retrieval of the regarding

Comment: Can you post `Task` class and `db.getAllTasks()` method.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I've added it, but I think it's not the problem

Comment: @PankajKumar After I'll implement it, is overriding adapter's `getView` still needed? Thanks

Comment: @PankajKumar It wasn't required, overriding toString helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to know that :) congs..

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the adapter's `getView` method and implement a `ViewHolder` pattern to handle displaying your `Task` objects.